# Why is mysql unable to configure?

Tags: server, mysql

I try to install mysql-server on my Ubuntu vps server, and it's able to install, but not to configure. If it tries to configure I get this:

```
>    ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.0 (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.0
     mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does someone know a solution to this?

Btw, my other question can be closed, it's solved, but I cant comment on it anymore.

Comment: Does /var/log/syslog show anything related to mysql when you attempt to configure the package?

Comment: I don't know really much about these things... how do you use /var/log/syslog?

Comment: It doesn't work, I get this error:

/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.0 is broken or not fully installed

Answer (score 1):

You probably aborted the mysql root password prompt dialog. From the terminal, run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.0
```

Let us know the results, please update your question or use the Add Comments feature.